# Cannot infer type arguments for Generic Class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create Expression Tree using the Postfix Expression.
This needs a Stack which could hold Tree Objects.
I created a generic Stack class which could except `<TreeTemp>` as type argument.

On trying to initialize the stack with following statement, its giving "Cannot infer type arguments for TreeStack<>" error.
`private TreeStack<TreeTemp> stack1 = new TreeStack<>(new TreeTemp());`
Stack Class:

```
public class TreeStack<T> {

    private T [] stackElem;
    private final int MAXSTACKSIZE;
    private int top;
    
    public TreeStack(Class<T> t) {
        top = -1;
        MAXSTACKSIZE = 20;
        final T[] stackElem = (T[]) Array.newInstance(t, MAXSTACKSIZE);
        this.stackElem = stackElem;
        
    }
    
    public void push(T elem) throws Exception{
        if(isFull()) {
            stackElem[++top] = elem;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Stack is already Full");
    }
    
    public T pop() throws Exception {
        
        if(isEmpty()) {
            return stackElem[top--];
        }
        else
            
            throw new Exception("Stack is Empty");
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {return top == -1;}
    
    public boolean isFull() {return top==MAXSTACKSIZE-1;}
}
```

Postfix.class(Class having method for creating tree)

```
public class PostFix {

    private String expression = new String("A*B+C");
    private char [] expElem = expression.toCharArray();
/*Error on below Statement*/

    private TreeStack<TreeTemp> stack1 = new TreeStack<>(new TreeTemp());
    
    public TreeTemp makeTree() throws Throwable {
        try {
        for(int i=0;i<expElem.length;i++) {
            ExpNode eNode = new ExpNode();
            eNode.setiData(expElem[i]);
            TreeTemp t = new TreeTemp();
            t.setRoot(eNode);
            if(!Character.isLetter(expElem[i])) {
                t.setLeftTree(stack1.pop());
                t.setRightTree(stack1.pop());   
                }
            stack1.push(t);
        }
        return stack1.pop();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Stack Error while creating a Tree", e);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        PostFix pf = new PostFix();
        TreeTemp t = pf.makeTree();
        
        
    }
```

Tree Class(Type which i want to add into Stack):

```
public class TreeTemp {
    
    private ExpNode root;
    private TreeTemp leftTree;
    private TreeTemp rightTree;
    
    /*public TreeTemp(ExpNode expNode) {
        root = expNode;

        }*/

    public TreeTemp getLeftTree() {
        return leftTree;
    }

    public void setLeftTree(TreeTemp leftTree) {
        this.leftTree = leftTree;
    }

    public TreeTemp getRightTree() {
        return rightTree;
    }

    public void setRightTree(TreeTemp rightTree) {
        this.rightTree = rightTree;
    }

    public ExpNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
    public void setRoot(ExpNode node) {
        this.root = node;
    }
}
```

Can someone pls give some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TreeStack` has only one constructor. Here it is:

```
public TreeStack(Class<T> t) {
```

Thus, to invoke it, you need to pass the class object that represents the class associated with the T type. So, the *class* itself, not 'some particular instance of T'. When you call it on your error line:

```
private TreeStack<TreeTemp> stack1 = new TreeStack<>(new TreeTemp());
```

You are passing an instance of TreeTemp. Not the concept 'TreeTemp, the class'. Try `new TreeStack<>(TreeTemp.class);`

Note that as a general rule, passing a `Class<T>` is a code smell; you're trying to make generics something that it isn't (you're trying to runtime reify). This is objectively bad: It means you can't make a `TreeStack<List<String>>`, for example, because you're restricted to the overlap where both generics as well as `j.l.Class` instances can represent the thing, and that's just simple, non-genericsed, non-primitive classes.

> `final T[] stackElem = (T[]) Array.newInstance(t, MAXSTACKSIZE);`

Looks like the only reason you want that class is to make sure your array is properly typed.

This is not neccessary. Just make a new `Object[]` array, and cast to T anytime you need to return a T. Now your TreeStack constructor needs no arguments at all.

Check the source of java.util.ArrayList, which agrees with this assessment; it is backed by an Object array, not a T[].

Comment: new TreeStack<>(TreeTemp.class) works perfectly. Regarding using Object [] instead, I would prefer going with T [] for not loosing the Type safety, as mentioned in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: You aren't 'loosening the type safety' by using Object. You _are_ making it impossible to make a TreeStack of e.g. an `AtomicReference<String>`. I would assume that the authors of something as important as ArrayList have a point, when they decided to go with Object[] instead of T[].

Answer (score 1):

The `TreeStack` constructor accepts a `Class<T>`, not a `T`, so you should do:

```
new TreeStack<>(TreeTemp.class);
```

Since this is an exercise to create expression trees, you don't really need to implement stacks from scratch. You should just use the `ArrayDeque` class through the `Deque` interface in the Java Collections API.

```
private Deque<TreeTemp> stack1 = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

[`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) has all the methods your `TreeStack` has, and many more.